# What is the runtimeDescriptorArray in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

There is a feature called runtimeDescriptorArray:

> indicates whether the implementation supports the SPIR-V
> RuntimeDescriptorArray capability. If this feature is not enabled,
> descriptors must not be declared in runtime arrays.

What does it do? What is a runtime array?

Answer (score 1):

An array declaration in a shading language has a runtime-defined size if the size of that array is... not specified at compile time. In GLSL, you might declare such an array as follows:

```
ivec4 arr[];
```

Exactly where the actual size comes from depends on what the storage class of the variable is or where its resources come from. For example, if you declare such a variable as the final member of a storage buffer block, the size will be computed based on the size of the actual buffer in the descriptor that storage block is associated with. Binding different descriptors will change what `arr.length()` returns.

Side-note: `[]` doesn't *always* mean runtime-defined. For example, arrayed inputs or outputs of certain shader stages (geometry shaders, tessellation shaders) have a size that is determined by some other compile-time construct. The size of GS input arrays is determined by the input primitive type, which is compile-time defined. So those arrays have a compile-time size, even if you don't specify it explicitly.

Descriptor declarations can be arrayed. A single descriptor binding can contain multiple descriptors. In GLSL, this could be defined as follows:

```
layout(set = X, binding = Y) uniform sampler2D manyTextures[5];
```

`manyTextures` is a single binding that contains multiple 2D samplers.

A "runtime descriptor array" is a combination of the two: a descriptor array whose size is not defined at compile-time. In this case, the actual size comes from the size specified by the descriptor set *layout* used at the time of rendering.